# Springboot @Transactional annotation not working with datasource

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate

I am trying to configure springBoot to have 2 datasources ('pims' & 'powwow') by following [this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-multiple-databases) tutorial.

It kind of works, but only for the `@Primary` datasource.  How do I get it to work for the other datasource?

**application.properties**

```
# pims datasource
spring.datasource1.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource1.jdbc-url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/pims
spring.datasource1.username=postgres
spring.datasource1.password=postgres
# powwow datasource
spring.datasource2.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource2.jdbc-url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/powwow
spring.datasource2.username=postgres
spring.datasource2.password=postgres
```

**PersistencePimsAutoConfiguration.java**

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource({"classpath:application.properties"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = {"com.clubtravel.powwow.dao.pims", "com.clubtravel.powwow.repositories.pims"},
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "pimsEntityManager",
        transactionManagerRef = "pimsTransactionManager")
public class PersistencePimsAutoConfiguration {

    private Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(PersistencePimsAutoConfiguration.class);

    @Value("${spring.datasource1.jdbc-url}")
    private String url;
    @Value("${spring.datasource1.username}")
    private String username;
    @Value("${spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto}")
    private String hbm2ddl;
    @Value("${spring.jpa.database-platform}")
    private String platform;
    @Value("${spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect}")
    private String dialect;
    @Value("${spring.profiles.active}")
    private String profile;

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.datasource1")
    public DataSource pimsDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    //@Bean(name = "pimsEntityManager")
    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean pimsEntityManager() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(pimsDataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] {"com.clubtravel.powwow.entities.pims"});
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", hbm2ddl);
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", dialect);
        em.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);
        String host = null;
        try {
            host = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        logger.info("Setting spring.datasource1 (pims): hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto='"+hbm2ddl+"', platform='"+platform+"', url='"+url+"', username='"+username+"', host='"+host+"', profile='"+profile+"'.");
        return em;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager pimsTransactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(pimsEntityManager().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

**PersistencePowwowAutoConfiguration.java**

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource({"classpath:application.properties"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = {"com.clubtravel.powwow.dao.powwow", "com.clubtravel.powwow.repositories.powwow"},
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "powwowEntityManager",
        transactionManagerRef = "powwowTransactionManager")
public class PersistencePowwowAutoConfiguration {

    private Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(PersistencePowwowAutoConfiguration.class);

    @Value("${spring.datasource2.jdbc-url}")
    private String url;
    @Value("${spring.datasource2.username}")
    private String username;
    @Value("${spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto}")
    private String hbm2ddl;
    @Value("${spring.jpa.database-platform}")
    private String platform;
    @Value("${spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect}")
    private String dialect;
    @Value("${spring.profiles.active}")
    private String profile;

    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.datasource2")
    public DataSource powwowDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    //@Bean(name = "powwowEntityManager")
    @Bean
    @Primary
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean powwowEntityManager() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(powwowDataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.clubtravel.powwow.entities.powwow" });
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", hbm2ddl);
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", dialect);
        em.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);
        String host = null;
        try {
            host = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        logger.info("Setting spring.datasource2 (powwow): hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto='"+hbm2ddl+"', platform='"+platform+"', url='"+url+"', username='"+username+"', host='"+host+"', profile='"+profile+"'.");
        return em;
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public PlatformTransactionManager powwowTransactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(powwowEntityManager().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

I thought that when I used the secondary datasource, if I added the `@Trannsactional` annotation, it would work.

e.g.

**MerchantsDao.java**

```
@Transactional("pimsTransactionManager")
public List<MerchantsEntity> findByCustomerNumber(String customerNumber) {
    Query qry = entityManager.createNamedQuery("Merchants.findByCustomerNo");
    qry.setParameter(1, customerNumber);
    List<MerchantsEntity> entities = (List<MerchantsEntity>) qry.getResultList();
    return entities;
}
```

However, it says it cannot find the query:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No query defined for that name
> [Merchants.findByCustomerNo]

I also try adding `@Transactional("pimsTransactionManager")` at the DAO's class level, but still get the same error above.  If I switch the `@Primary` annotation to the 'pimsTransactionManager' datasource beans, then that datasources works but the 'powwowTransactionManager' datasource gets this error.

So it looks like even though I define two datasources, it only works  with the primary one.

Comment: I think "findByCustomerNo" is not created by the spring data jpa 
you should try to generate an interface extends JpaRepository or CrudRepository

Comment: @JoonseoLee thank you, that solved my problem.  If I move the queries to the repository (from the entity) it works.